# TYPO3 special menu "browse"

Tags: menu, typo3, typoscript

I'm trying to build a browse menu in TYPO3 that should be added to all subpages to navigate trough all submenu pages.

That's what I got:

```
temp.prevPage = HMENU    
temp.prevPage {
    special = browse
    special{
        items = prev
        value = 22
        prev.fields.title = <img src="fileadmin/dev/pics/prev.gif" title="next page" alt="prev page"/>
    }
    1 = TMENU
    1.NO = 1
    1.NO.allWrap = |
}
temp.nextPage = HMENU
    temp.nextPage {    
    special = browse
    special{        
        items = next
        value = 22
        next.fields.title = <img src="fileadmin/dev/pics/next.gif" title="next page" alt="prev page" />
    }
    1 = TMENU
    1.NO = 1
    1.NO.allWrap = |
}
```

To the Problem: The next and prev arrows are shown on any pid value correctly but it doesn't work if it is the pid of the actual page (actually I could leave value away, then it should work on the actual page but it doesn't).

Example: I'm currently on page with id (pid) 23, there the links to pid 21 (prev) and to 23 (next) are shown. But if I go to page with id 22, the links to prev an next disapear.

Template is on _root.

Menu-Tree:

```
_root
- Home
- pid19
- - pid20
- - pid21
- - pid22
- - pid23
- pid24
- - pid25
...
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `special.value` to always take the current pid. It could look something like this (slightly different, but copied from a live project):

```
lib.navi.horizontal = COA
lib.navi.horizontal {
    10 = HMENU
    10 {
        special = browse
        special {
            items = prev
        }
        1 = TMENU
        1.noBlur = 1
        1.NO {
            ATagParams = class="nav-arrow nav-prev"
            ATagTitle.dataWrap = {field:title}
        }
    }
    20 = HMENU
    20 {
        special = browse
        special {
            items = next
        }
        1 = TMENU
        1.noBlur = 1
        1.NO {
            ATagParams = class="nav-arrow nav-next"
            ATagTitle.dataWrap = {field:title}
        }
    }
}
```

This code has to go on pid 19 in your page structure

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, that's what I originally tried: The TS without value. But it didn't work and still doesn't work. Then I found out, that it's only a problem on the actual page because I tried it out with a manual pid value.

Comment: I tried it with your code, 1to1, didn't work as well. There must be a problem somewhere else. Is there any setting? Or something to change in options or include someting?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, my code would need to go on pid 19 in your code to be available on all sub pages..

Comment: Thanks so much, you gave me the key to the answer: The TS has to be on the parent page, not in the _root... Now it works!

Comment: Simple and efficient, works out-of-the-box, good snippet